# Cisco IP Prefix List Question

Tags: cisco, routing

Can someone please let me know if the prefix `ip prefix-list emea seq 30 permit 10.9.1.0/24 ge 25` will include 10.9.1.0/24 network, or just 10.9.1.0./25, 10.9.1.0./26 etc if they existed?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two statements to allow /24 and greater

```
prefix-list emea seq 30 permit 10.9.1.0/24
prefix-list emea seq 31 permit 10.9.1.0/24 ge 25
```

Comment: John K, that is what I used in the end. Cheers

Comment: You can easily do the same with 1 statement: emea seq 30 permit 10.9.1.0/24 le 32. And this does not answer the original question...

Comment: You are correct :)  I can't delete the post because it was accepted.

Answer (score 4):

The `ge 25` suffix basically requires the prefix length to be 25 or higher (ge = greater than or equal).

In other words, the entry could be rephrased to: permit any network which is inside the network 10.9.1.0/24 and has a prefix length of 25 or higher. This would include 10.9.1.0/25, 10.9.1.0/26 as you have indicated (up to /32 as the `le n` attribute is omitted) but not 10.9.1.0/24.

It would however also include things like 10.9.1.128/25 or 10.9.1.200/30, as all those networks are within the 10.9.1.0/24 network having a subnet mask greater than or equal to 25.

Another example would be `prefix-list emea seq 30 permit 10.9.1.0/24 ge 25 le 25`.

This would exactly match the following two prefixes:

10.9.1.0/25 and 10.9.1.128/25

As the logic now is: permit any networks within the 10.9.1.0/24 range which prefix length is greater than or equal 25 **and** lower than or equal 25, in other words, exactly 25.

Comment: Hi @waza-ari, I got most of your last statement apart from 'exactly 25'. The key is that the prefix will include 10.9.1.0/24, /25, /26 etc.

Comment: In my second example with `ge 25 le 25` the key is that the prefix length must be exactly /25 in order to be matched. Consider it that way: the prefix length has to be both greater than **or equal** to 25 and lower than **or equal** to 25 at the same time, which leaves us with an exact match of 25.

Comment: No worries. If that answer answers your question, please consider marking it as helpful such that others have an indication.